# How to inject “Chart.js” to my module?

Tags: angularjs, charts, module, chart.js

This is my Html. I have given paths like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

     <script type="text/javascript" href="/node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/components/root/root.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/components/imgComponent/imgComponent.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/components/typesComponent/typesComponent.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/components/sourceComponent/sourceComponent.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/components/severitiesComponent/severitiesComponent.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />

</head>
<body ng-app="appModule">
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

In my script I wrote:

```
'use strict';

const appModule = angular.module('appModule',["chart.js"]);

appModule.component('appSeveritiesComponent', {
    templateUrl: '/app/components/severitiesComponent/severitiesComponent.html',
    controller: severitiesComponentController,
    bindings: {
    }
});

severitiesComponentController.$inject = [];

function severitiesComponentController() {
}
```

When I am using in my application it is giving error

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

How to solve this error?

Comment: you don't have an `angular.js` script in your HTML code (it should say `angular` is not defined). Also check your error for any link that may explain the problem better

Answer (score 0):

You are missing reference for angular.js

add the reference for angular.js above

```
  <script type="text/javascript" href="/node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: its was been installed using npm (I dont get error about it )

Comment: but you have not refered it

Comment: if i insert the script into my code i get a warning : 
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Comment: @TomCohen include that script in your question, because we can't see it. The problem can be with the **order** of scripts. `angular.js` should come before other libraries that use `angular.module`

Comment: look at the error text :    Failed to instantiate module appModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module chart.js due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart.js' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/$injector/nomod?p0=chart.js

Answer (score 0):

The order of your scripts matter. If you look at the **Installation** section on [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), you will see the following order:

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

`Chart.js` should come **before** `angular-chart.js`

Moreover, you also need `angular.js` script inserted before those two.

Comment: but when i add the angular.js i got a WARNING that angular included twice.
in additional, when I add const appModule = angular.module('appModule',['chart.js']); my app got crazy...

Comment: @TomCohen **script**, not module. I mean this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @TomCohen check if you already have it somewhere in your HTML. Your question doesn't have it, so I assumed you need it.